# `+': Fracpri can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)

Tags: ruby

Code:

```
class Fracpri

attr_accessor:whole, :numer, :denom, :dec, :flofrac
def initialize()
    puts "Hey! It's an empty constructor"
end
def getFraction(whole,numer,denom)
    @whole=whole
    @numer=numer
    @denom=denom
end
def showFraction
    puts "#{whole} #{numer}/#{denom}"
end
def +(obj)
    puts "Before adding the constant:  #{whole} #{numer}/#{denom}"
    obj.whole= self + obj.whole
    obj.numer= self + obj.numer
    obj.denom= self + obj.denom
    puts "After adding the constant x=#{obj}:  #{whole} #{numer}/#{denom}"
end
end

r3=Fracpri.new()
r3.getFraction(1,2,3)
r2=Fracpri.new()
r2.getFraction(4,6,5)
r1=Fracpri.new()
r1.getFraction(4,6,5)

r3=5+r1
```

i'm getting a error here for this operation

I cant overload this operator,it shows an error "`+': Fracpri can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)"

Comment: `5` is a `Fixnum` when `r1` is a `Fracpri`. what is the expected result of the adding you want here?

Comment: i need to add that 5 to all the members of r1 @Thang

Answer (score 0):

`5` is an `Integer`. `Integer#+` requires that the argument must be an `Integer`, properly implement the `coerce` protocol, or respond to `to_int`. Your `Fracpri` does not do any of that.

Comment: It's hard to give more concrete advice than this, since the code is so fundamentally broken that making it work essentially requires to throw it away and start from scratch. Just from a cursory glance, I see at least 15 problems of varying degrees of severity.